# How do I use a select statement to set a variable and use it in a case statement

Tags: t-sql

I am using a case statement to determine the Count(*) of several different age groups, but I need to get the percentage of each age group as it pertains to the Total of all age groups.
I know this is a newbie question but I am stuck. 
Thanks
Andy

Here is the code I am trying to use.

```
WITH AgeGroups AS ( 
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) < 21 THEN 'Under   21' 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 21 AND 29 THEN '21 - 29' 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30 - 39' 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40 - 49'
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50 - 59' 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) > 60 THEN '60 and Over' 
ELSE 'Unkown' 
END AS AgeGroup  
FROM party   
LEFT OUTER JOIN volunteer on partyID = volunteer.partyID 
WHERE volunteer.swornDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) 
SELECT  AgeGroup, COUNT(*) AS AgeGroupCount, Convert(decimal(18,2),  
(1.0*Count(*)/@Total * 100)) as percentage 

FROM AgeGroups 
GROUP BY AgeGroup
```

I am trying to fill the variable @Total with the count of all age groups

Comment: Can you post some sample SQL?  You will probably need to use subquery to calculate total, then calculate percentages off of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it is not clear whether you want to fill the @Total or generate the query output.

If it is the later then this may work for you.

```
WITH AgeGroups AS ( 
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) < 21 THEN 'Under   21' 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 21 AND 29 THEN '21 - 29' 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30 - 39' 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40 - 49'
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50 - 59' 
WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, party.birthdate, GETDATE()) > 60 THEN '60 and Over' 
ELSE 'Unkown' 
END AS AgeGroup,
FROM party   
LEFT OUTER JOIN volunteer on partyID = volunteer.partyID 
WHERE volunteer.swornDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
) 
SELECT  AgeGroup,COUNT(*) AS AgeGroupCount,  Convert(decimal(18,2),  
(1.0*Count(*)/b.totcnt * 100)) as percentage 

FROM AgeGroups a,
(select COUNT(*) AS totcnt from AgeGroups) b

GROUP BY a.AgeGroup
```

Comment: @andycicchillo in that case, chose this as your answer